# Images loading again even after preloading

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks, preloading

I am trying to preload images and set them as background in the React HOC component, but despite loading it the css is calling and caching the Images again.

```js
interface ImagePreloaderProps {
  pictures: string[];
  interval?: number;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const ImagePreloader: React.FC<ImagePreloaderProps> = ({ pictures, interval = 3000, children }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [imagesLoaded, setImagesLoaded] = useState(false);
  console.log('vhdc in the ImagePreloader', imagesLoaded);

  useEffect(() => {
    const preloadImages = async () => {
      const promises = pictures.map((url) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          const img = new Image();
          img.src = url;
          img.onload = () => resolve(img);
        });
      });

      try {
        await Promise.all(promises);
        setImagesLoaded(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error preloading images:', error);
      }
    };

    preloadImages();
  }, [pictures]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % pictures.length);
    }, interval);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [pictures, interval]);

  const imageContainers = pictures.map((url, index) => (
    <div
      key={url}
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        display: index === currentIndex ? 'block' : 'none',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  ));

  return <>{imagesLoaded && imageContainers}</>;
};
```

Following the screenshots of the network Tab where I have already preloaded images it is called again by css as other initiator.

Please Refer to the following Img Network calls.

[Network for called by component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPEop.png)

[Other as the initiator for the Css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIPWX.png)